# Black bar at the bottom after update to iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, ios8.1

I have an app on the store and I started working on the update for iOS 8 a while ago, everything seemed to work fine except for this problem I'm having with the layouts. No matter what device I test the app on, there's always a black bar at the bottom (or the side on landscape mode).

[image: Test on iPhone 5s]
Test on iPhone 5S

[image: Test on iPhone 4s]
Test on iPhone 4S

Is this an issue with iOS 8? How can I solve it?

Comment: Show your code. How are you initially configuring the window? How are you initially configuring the root view?

Comment: Also mention using which XCode you are building your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the thin bar along one side when an iOS 8 device was rotated to landscape.  I found the solution to this problem here: [Building project with Xcode 6 (iOS 8 SDK) causes landscape rotation rendering issue on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265118/building-project-with-xcode-6-ios-8-sdk-causes-landscape-rotation-rendering-is/29287389#29287389)

The fix I did was to go to MainWindow.xib, select the Window, then go to the Attributes inspector and select the two check boxes for **Visible at Launch** and **Full Screen at Launch**.